# Java Problem with super.paintComponents(g), it makes a print screen

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm trying to make a paint in java, with classes and hierarchy. But my paint area isn't getting the background color (defined as white) and when i click it makes a print screen in the jpanel area of drawing. With super.paintComponent(g) the interface appears all right but i only get one point of each time. With super.paintComponents(g) it prints the frame in the jpanel area.

any thoughts about what's happen?

```
public class MandaDesenhar extends JPanel
{
static int x;
static int y;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
int i = 0;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{   
    super.paintComponents(g);

    if (Paint4Fun.lista.size() == 0)
        return;

    while (i<Paint4Fun.lista.size())
    {
        FormaPrimitiva forma = Paint4Fun.lista.get(i);
        forma.desenha(g);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define `i` locally in your `paintComponent` method, not outside of it, and initialize it there to `0`.

Otherwise you are always only painting the new elements of your list, not the older ones.

**Edit:**
You can write your loop better as a for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Paint4Fun.lista.size(); i++) {
   FormaPrimitiva forma = Paint4Fun.lista.get(i);
   forma.desenha(g); 
}
```

or even more clearly:

```
for(FormaPrimitiva forma : Paint4Fun.lista) {
    forma.desenha(g);
}
```

Generally, always declare variables (like the `i` here) in the smallest possible scope (the method or even the loop, here).

Comment: Worked really well. Many thanks, I passed more or less the last 5 hours just trying to solve this.